# How do I get the event handler of an overlay object?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, event-handling

I have a marker on the map with some event handler bound to it.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
```

How do I get the event handler without assigning the handler a global name? such as:

```
var h = function(){
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    }
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', h);
```

This is too complex.

What I am looking for is like `marker.mouseover` (just like a DOM element) but this does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found an alternative.
`trigger(instance:Object, eventName:string, var_args:*)` will trigger the event bound. And this fulfill almost all needs.